# Return results where a shared value is shared between two tables and the timestamp is different

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables 1 and 2, and I want to return all results where the following are true:

1. The Values in Column A match in both tables
2. The Timestamp in column B is Greater in table 1 than table 2 for entries that match.

I'm running into a problem where my subquery is returning more than 1 value and I'm a bit of a loss on how to structure the second portion of my query. Can anyone provide some guidance?

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results instead of a word problem, thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a simple join, can you show your SQL code?

Comment: Looks like it was a simple join, I didn't realize I could the > function in the join.

SELECT * from TABLE1 A 
LEFT join TABLE2 B
ON A.SourceID=B.SourceID
where A.Updated<B.Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 AS a INNER JOIN Table2 AS b
ON a.ValueA = b.ValueA
WHERE a.ValueB > b.ValueB
```

Not sure what the exact issue you are having is, but I don't see why this wouldn't work.